# How to get x_train and y_train from ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on some image classification problem and I made Y Network for it. Y Network is a type of Neural Network which has two inputs and one output. If we want to fit our Tensorflow model we have to feed x_train and y_train in model.fit().
Like this -

```
model.fit([x_train, x_train], y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=64)
```

but how do I get **x_train** and **y_train** if I got my data from **ImageDataGenerator** ? Like this -

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(... , batch_size=64, ...)
```

I tried getting x_train and y_train by this method:

```
x_train, y_train = train_generator.next()
```

but resulted x_train and y_train consist of only **64** images, I want all my **8644** images. I cannot increase batch_size to **8644** because it will need more memory and Google Colab will crash. What should I do ?

Comment: Wouldn't loading all the images at once then cause Colab to crash as well?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. @yudhiesh

Comment: You said if you were to load all the images in a single batch for training it would crash your Colab env yet you want to do the same based on this question. Why not loop over `range(0, NUM_IMAGES//BATCH_SIZE + 1)` and yield the images?

Comment: @Hobo, thnx for the explanation on theta transpose x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the list of all images and labels from

```
class_dict=train_generator.class_indices
labels= train_generator.labels
file_names= train_generator.filenames
```

the class dictionary is useful to correlate the class index to the class name, it is of the form {class name, index} I find it useful to reverse the order to get a dictionary of the form {index, class name} using the code below

```
for key,value in class_dict.items():
        new_dict[value]=key
```

So when you do predictions and get the index of the prediction using index= np.argmax(p) you can get the corresponding class name from

```
class_name=new_dict[index]
```